# Overriding a forms OnPaint method in component class

Tags: c#, winforms, winforms-interop

Im looking to override the OnPaint method of the parent form of my component..

However i face 2 errors while doing this, the first is assigning the parent forms event handler

1. No overload for "OnPaint" matches delegate "PaintEventHandler"
2. Member from "Region.FromHrgn(IntPtr)" cannot be accessed with an instance reference; Qualify it with a type name instead.

heres my code

```
    private Control hostControl;
    public override ISite Site
        {
            get { return base.Site; }
            set
            {
                base.Site = value;
                if (value == null)
                {
                    return;
                }

                IDesignerHost host = value.GetService(typeof(IDesignerHost)) as IDesignerHost;
                if (host != null)
                {
                    IComponent componentHost = host.RootComponent;
                    if (componentHost is ContainerControl)
                    {
                        hostControl = componentHost as ContainerControl;
                        hostControl.FindForm().Paint += new PaintEventHandler(this.OnPaint);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnPaint(e);
            hostControl.Region = hostControl.Region.FromHrgn(CreateTriangle(0, 0, this.Width, this.Height, this.Width, this.Height));
        }
```

Where am i going wrong?

Comment: No problem getting the parent form of the component but i cant assign the OnPaint event to it

Comment: OnPaint() is a method, not an event handler. Its job is to raise the control's Paint event, not to handle it. Changing the Region property in a Paint event handler is very unwise, it causes the Paint event to get raised again. Your program will be burning 100% core. The HandleCreated event is normally the correct event to use, but you don't know the final size of the host yet and that always matters for Region.  Since you demand it to be a Form, you can use the Load event instead.  Pretty evil btw, the Form class itself should determine what it looks like.

Comment: @HansPassant problem solved, however i still get an error while trying to set Region fromHrgn.
This is what i have now got

Comment: `((Form)sender).Region = ((Form)sender).Region.FromHrgn(CreateTriangle(0, 0, ((Form)sender).Width, ((Form)sender).Height, ((Form)sender).Width, ((Form)sender).Height));`

Comment: Got it, simple mistake, `((Form)sender).Region = Region.FromHrgn`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Overriding the `OnPaint()` method of a control is normally recommended for custom drawing of **THAT** control, not of drawing another control. What you are trying to do in your code is to attach the `Paint` event of the hosting form to the `OnPaint()` method of your control. That's probably not working.

As you can read in the MSDN documentation, the `Paint` event of a control is raised by the `OnPaint()` method. You can attach a custom event handler:

```
hostControl.FindForm().Paint += new PaintEventHandler(Form_Paint);

private void Paint(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e)
{
  ...
}
```

In the `PaintEventArgs` argument you will get the required parameters for drawing.